Github actions and Terragrunt - Plan file output path
I'm using Github actions to setup a Terragrunt pipeline, with Gruntwork IO Terragrunt action.
name: Deploy customer changes
on: push

env:
  TF_VERSION: 1.5.1
  TG_VERSION: 0.55.21

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  terragrunt-plan:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Plan
        uses: gruntwork-io/terragrunt-action@v2
        env:
          INPUT_PRE_EXEC_1: |
            git config --global url."https://oauth2:${{ secrets.ABC_TEST_ORG_CICD_TOKEN }}@github.com".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com"
        with:
          tf_version: ${{ env.TF_VERSION }}
          tg_version: ${{ env.TG_VERSION }}
          tg_dir: ${{ env.WORKING_DIR }}/00_aft
          tg_command: plan -out $(pwd)terragrunt.tfplan

Now, I want to output the Terragrunt plan file to pass it to the next Job (apply, not part of this question). This is the last line of the above file.
tg_command: plan -out $(pwd)terragrunt.tfplan

This works, but I have no idea why. To me, it should be with a / or using path with environment variable such as for example
tg_command: plan -out {{ github.workspace }}/terragrunt.tfplan
tg_command: plan -out "{{ github.workspace }}/terragrunt.tfplan"
tg_command: plan -out $(pwd)/terragrunt.tfplan

I have checked if $(pwd) have a trailing /, it doesn't.
The error I have using this command is
╷
│ Error: Failed to write plan file
│ 
│ The plan file could not be written: open
│ /home/runner/work/<path>/terragrunt.tfplan:
│ no such file or directory.
╵

I also tried creating an empty plan file prior to populate it, with no luck.
What am I missing?

Just to be sure: Using plan -out $(pwd)terragrunt.tfplan works, but using the same command with /  and plan -out {{ github.workspace }}/terragrunt.tfplan doesn't. Is that the issue? (if yes, did you also asked to the maintainers on the action repo?)

Yes, that's exactly the issue. Didn't yet created a GH issue, but I will if there's no answer here :)

Have you tried e.g. plan -out "${{ github.workspace }}/terragrunt.tfplan"?

The action source code seems to be shell script, so this line is where the command is read.

Yep, same result. I've updated my answer to reflect I tried that as well.

I managed to make it work with a combination of commands.
See the comments from the Github issue I raised

https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-action/issues/55#issuecomment-2051390294

